# Accidentally sent a general-purpose resume to a niche company. How should I correct it?

Tags: resume, job-search, recruitment

After lay-offs in my current company I was forced to job search on the market. During the process, I found a company specializing in a niche technology that I did my BSc with. I also use this technology for hobbyist work - however, I generally do not include the work in my general-purpose CV.

Not thinking much about it, I have sent the general-purpose CV to the company. I have yet to receive a response and I'm starting to worry that because my knowledge about this field is not highlighted in the resume, they have decided to skip me over.

Can I correct the mistake? If so, how should I proceed?

Comment: How long ago was it? Did you also send a cover letter? If it was recent you could try following up with a "oops forgot to attach a cover letter" and write all about the niche stuff in there

Comment: @Bee It was around a week ago. Do you think it'll slide?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Should I offer any explanation?

Comment: @Adam, if by "sent it to the company" you meant you uploaded it through a web-portal, I would not worry about it. If you are a uniquely qualified candidate, try to make contact with an actual hiring manager or other non-HR person and proceed from there with correctly detailed CV. Semi-anonymous web uploads are always shot in the dark even in the best case scenario.

Comment: @Bee No one reads cover letters.  HR doesn't forward them to us and HR's software doesn't even scan them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Given this was a week ago and you haven't heard back I'd just send a follow up email with something like the following:

> Hi blah,
>
> I sent over my CV last week but realised I didn't send across a cover letter to explain why I so interested in this *[niche technology]*. Please see the attached.
>
> Thanks
> Adam

Or something along those lines.

Nothing to lose by trying!

Comment: No one reads cover letters. HR doesn't forward them to us and HR's software doesn't even scan them.